How to create custom tab bar flutter
My code like this :
TabBar(
                          controller: _tabController,
                          isScrollable: false,
                          dividerColor: Colors.transparent,
                          indicator: const UnderlineTabIndicator(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.green, width: 4.0),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(25)),
                            insets: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 70.0, vertical: 17),
                          ),
                          indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,
                          labelColor: Colors.black,
                          unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey,
                          tabs: [
                            Tab(child: _buildTab(text: 'Phone', isSelected: _selectedIndex == 0)),
                            Tab(child: _buildTab(text: 'Email', isSelected: _selectedIndex == 1)),
                          ],
                        ),

and for _buildTab widget like this :

  Widget _buildTab({required String text, required bool isSelected}) {
    return Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      width: double.infinity,
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
          topLeft: Radius.circular(25),
          topRight: Radius.circular(25),
        ),
      ),
      child: Text(
        text,
        style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 18,
          color: isSelected ? Colors.black : Colors.black,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

how to create TabBar like radius in middle tab-bar, honestly i'm stuck for custom this one. please help

Share image that you want to create.

You can user flutter_custom_tab_bar package to have a rounded indicator.
